# Move position of an application window from the command line on OSX

Tags: command-line, osx, window-geometry

An application — [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/) — somehow got stuck off screen with only the corner showing. I can't grab it or use other means to move it from that position.

All new windows open in that position, regardless of if I open/close the application.

Is there a terminal command for moving a specific window's position?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html):

```
$ osascript \
    -e 'tell application "Terminal"' \
    -e 'set position of front window to {1, 1}' \
    -e 'end tell'
```

This isn't guaranteed to work. It's up to the app itself whether it will obey this command. You can try something like `set bounds of front window to {1, 1, 800, 600}` if it refuses to move the window. That will also resize it, but that might be a good thing, depending on how screwed up the window is.

I've broken the long command up purely for readability. It's fine to give it all as a single line, without the backslashes.

And yes, you need multiple `-e` options. AppleScript is a line-based language, so each line has to be given separately. You could run [`osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) without arguments and type the three lines by hand at it instead, if you prefer.